# GNU screen is slow exiting

Tags: bash, cygwin, gnu-screen

I've set up my `.bashrc` to automatically `screen -DRA` (even though it's a local session).

`screen` works fine, except that if I run `exit` from the last window or otherwise close it from the client itself, it pauses for about 20 seconds before closing itself. Any ideas why?

Side note: Another, possibly separate, possibly related problem I'm having is that whenever starting a shell I see the message 'Attaching from inside of screen?'

I'm using Cygwin Setup.exe version 2.871 (64 bit), GNU bash 4.3.39(2)-release, and xfce4-terminal 0.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

If it is OK for you to keep the screen running in the background, you can leave it by pressing Ctrl+A Ctrl+D  ("ade"~bye)

Comment: This question is long since irrelevant (the issue resolved itself ages ago with some probably-irrelevant thing), but thanks for telling me.